# jaxb output in String

Tags: java, jaxb

i want to get my generated xml output in a string Type container and further want to display that string in console.

```
try {

            file = new File(XMLName);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(ActivityXmlV1.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(activityXmlV1, file);
          //jaxbMarshaller.marshal(activityXmlV1, System.out);
            xmlData=asString(jaxbContext, activityXmlV1);
            System.out.println(xmlData);
            System.out.println("Sucess!!");
        } catch (UnmarshalException ue) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this...

```
public String asString(JAXBContext pContext, Object pObject)throws JAXBException {
        java.io.StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Marshaller marshaller = pContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.marshal(pObject, sw);
        return sw.toString();
    }
```

and call this method where u want t execute by :

```
System.out.println(asString(jaxbContext,activityXmlV1));
```